# populate form select dropdown based on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down that looks like this :

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

How can I pre populate the value to saab, based on the url. I have links on a different page, one for each of these options. I want people to be able to selct the link "saab", some how pass that though the url and make "saab" selected when the page with this form loads.
 Preferably a java script solution if possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a hyperlink that directs to a page with pre-selected option in a drop-down menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207583/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-that-directs-to-a-page-with-pre-selected-option-in-a-d)

Comment: This solution looks promising let me review and get back to you with my updates. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `window`'s `location` and parsing out the `pathname` should do the trick. Then all you have to do is set the `selected` attribute on the appropriate `option` in your `select` drop-down.

**Note:** This code does not require any dependencies.

```js
function main() {
  var url = new URLParser(window.location);
  var path = url.pathname;

  //Say our pathname is "/saab"
  path = '/saab';

  var selectEl = document.getElementById('make');
  for (var i = 0; i < selectEl.length; i++) {
    var optionEl = selectEl.options[i];
    if (optionEl.value === path.substr(1)) {
      optionEl.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
  }
}

// I wrote this URL parser a while back. It should be cross-browser safe.
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/27964708/1762224
var URLParser = (function(document) {
  var PROPS = 'protocol hostname host pathname port search hash href'.split(' ');
  var self = function(url) {
    this.aEl = document.createElement('a');
    this.parse(url);
  };
  self.prototype.parse = function(url) {
    this.aEl.href = url;
    if (this.aEl.host == "") {
      this.aEl.href = this.aEl.href;
    }
    PROPS.forEach(function(prop) {
      switch (prop) {
        case 'hash':
          this[prop] = this.aEl[prop].substr(1);
          break;
        default:
          this[prop] = this.aEl[prop];
      }
    }, this);
    if (this.pathname.indexOf('/') !== 0) {
      this.pathname = '/' + this.pathname;
    }
    this.requestUri = this.pathname + this.search;
  };
  self.prototype.toObj = function() {
    var obj = {};
    PROPS.forEach(function(prop) {
      obj[prop] = this[prop];
    }, this);
    obj.requestUri = this.requestUri;
    return obj;
  };
  self.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.href;
  };
  return self;
})(document);

main();
```

```html
<select id="make">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```