# Select form value depending on URL

Tags: php, html, string, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a dropdown box to select based on the URL. I would like the url

http://example.com/login.php?port=2095

or something similar to automatically select Webmail on load and for ?port=2082 to select cPanel?

Here is my form

```
<form action="cplogin.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
Login To:

 <select name="port">
 <option value="2082">cPanel</option>
 <option value="2083">Secure cPanel</option>
 <option value="2095">Webmail</option>
 <option value="2096">Secure Webmail</option>
 </select>

 <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" style="cursor:pointer">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have look online  but can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a hyperlink that directs to a page with pre-selected option in a drop-down menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207583/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-that-directs-to-a-page-with-pre-selected-option-in-a-d)

Comment: You need a loop, and if-statement, and a knowledge of HTML.

Comment: @developerwjk Why does he need a loop and if-statement?

Comment: @Mathematician171 To do it in PHP would require looping through the options and building the HTML for the dropdown and checking each one to see if it was chosen. To do it in Javascript he doesn't.

Comment: @developerwjk He never says that he need to do it in PHP. Also, it can be done in a PHP without using any loops or if-statements.

Comment: @Mathematician171 I'd like to see how it can be done in PHP without a loop or if-statements.

Comment: @developerwjk Simple.
`<?php
echo '<script>var url=document.location.href; url=url.substring(url.length-4,url.length); document.getElementById(url).selected="selected";</script>';
?>`

Comment: @Mathematician171 Printing Javascript from PHP doesn't count as a pure PHP solution, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `id` attribute to each option, then using javascript make it selected.

```
<form action="cplogin.php" method="post">
Username:<input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
Password:<input type="password" name="pass"></td></tr>
Login To:

 <select name="port">
 <option value="2082" id="2082">cPanel</option>
 <option value="2083" id="2083">Secure cPanel</option>
 <option value="2095" id="2095">Webmail</option>
 <option value="2096" id="2096">Secure Webmail</option>
 </select>

 <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" style="cursor:pointer">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
    var url=document.location.href;
    url=url.substring(url.length-4,url.length);
    document.getElementById(url).selected="selected";
</script>
```