# Adding arguments in url to choose values in multiple drop downs on page using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a webpage where the content changes depending on which drop down options the user has selected. Once the user has made his first choice, the content of a drop down menu can be an additional nested drop down menu with another choice the user must make.

I am now trying to figure out how I can pre-select options by passing parameters in the URL for both the first drop down and a number of nestet drop downs.

I have the basic functionality down. Here's my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_select.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_drop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

<select id="select" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option id="one" value="noselection" data-show=".noselection">
        Choose option
    </option>
    <option id="two" value="2015" data-show=".2015">
        2015
    </option>
    <option id="three" value="2014" data-show=".2014">
        2014
    </option>
 </select>

<div class="my-info-1">
    <div class="noselection hide">
        No choice made
    </div>

    <div class="2015 hide">
        2015        
    </div>

    <div class="2014 hide">

        A nested drop down within the 2014 selection:<br><br>

            <select id="select" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-2">
                <option id="one" value="noselection2" data-show=".noselection2">
                    Choose option
                </option>
                <option id="two" value="s1" data-show=".s1">
                    January
                </option>
                <option id="three" value="s2" data-show=".s2">
                    February
                </option>
            </select>

            <div class="my-info-2">
                <div class="noselection2 hide">
                    No choice made
                </div>
                <div class="s1 hide">
                    Information about January   
                </div>
                <div class="s2 hide">
                    Information about February
                </div>
            </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my css.css:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

And here's js_drop.js that makes content appear depending on the user selection. I found the script here: [Change the content of a div based on selection from dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164507/change-the-content-of-a-div-based-on-selection-from-drop-down-menu):

```
$(document).on('change', '.div-toggle', function() {
  var target = $(this).data('target');
  var show = $("option:selected", this).data('show');
  $(target).children().addClass('hide');
  $(show).removeClass('hide');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.div-toggle').trigger('change');
});
```

I am now adding functionality to make it possible to link to a specific drop down selection and any nested selections by adding parameters to the URL, like in:

```
http://example.com/page.html?select=three&selectnested=two
```

I am using js_select.js for this function. I found the code here: [How to create a hyperlink that directs to a page with pre-selected option in a drop-down menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25207583/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-that-directs-to-a-page-with-pre-selected-option-in-a-d)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select = GetUrlParameter("select");
  $("#" + select).attr("selected", "");
});

function GetUrlParameter(name) {
    var value;
    $.each(window.location.search.slice(1).split("&"), function (i, kvp) {
        var values = kvp.split("=");
        if (name === values[0]) {
            value = values[1] ? values[1] : values[0];
            return false;
        }
    });
    return value;
}
```

My guess at a solution would be to:

- Change id on my second `<select>` to id="selectnested"
- Add the following code to my js_select.js above the function

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select = GetUrlParameter("selectnested");
  $("#" + select).attr("selected", "");
});
```

But this solution does not choose a selection with-in the nested drop down when the page loads using my example URL above.

Any hint on solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have multiple elements with the same ID (both `<select>`s have the ID `"select"`, the `<option>`s have repeated IDs `"one"`, `"two"` and `"three"`).

Change the IDs of the `<select>` and `<option>` elements so they don't conflict with each other.

Example:

```
<select id="select" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1">
    <option id="select-one" value="noselection" data-show=".noselection">
        Choose option
    </option>
    <option id="select-two" value="2015" data-show=".2015">
        2015
    </option>
    <option id="select-three" value="2014" data-show=".2014">
        2014
    </option>
</select>
...
<select id="nested" class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-2">
    <option id="nested-one" value="noselection2" data-show=".noselection2">
        Choose option
    </option>
    <option id="nested-two" value="s1" data-show=".s1">
        January
    </option>
    <option id="nested-three" value="s2" data-show=".s2">
        February
    </option>
</select>
```

This way, in your initialization function, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // First selection menu options
    var select = GetUrlParameter("select");
    $("#select-" + select).attr("selected", "");

    // "Nested" selection menu options
    var select = GetUrlParameter("selectnested");
    $("#nested-" + select).attr("selected", "");
});
```

And due to those prefixes (`select-` and `nested-`) jQuery will only find *one* element with that ID, and you'll hopefully have no more trouble!